# Datanitro python script not executing in workbook_open()

Tags: excel, datanitro, vba

In ThisWorkbook Excel Object I have the following two subroutines:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello World"

    Call call_DN

End Sub

Sub call_DN()
    Application.COMAddIns("DataNitro.DataNitro").Object.RunScript ("test.py")
    MsgBox "called sub"
End Sub
```

When I open the workbook I see the "Hello World" message box and then the "called sub" message box but the python script does not execute.

However, when I then manually run Workbook_Open() the python script does execute properly.

Why is the python script not executing upon application startup?

No error messages are being thrown - it seems that the .runscript command is just being ignored.

Comment: What does "test.py" do?

Comment: It is a single line....Cell("A9").value = 1

Comment: The more general problem is that while windows task scheduler can call a python script, Datanitro must be initiated from within an open excel workbook.  Accordingly, the only method I am aware of to make use of Datanitro via windows task scheduler is to have task scheduler open the excel file and then call the datanitro script from the Workbook_Open() subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNitro has an [autostart](https://datanitro.com/docs/scripts.html#autostart) option for calling a script on workbook start. Please use that rather than VBA's workbook open hook.

(The workbook open hook should work in theory, but it looks like it doesn't.)